# gradle: kotlin("jvm") vs id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In `gradle.build.kts`, is there any difference between following two

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.31" // simple way
}

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31" // indirect way
}
```

**Is there any reason not to use `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")`?**

Context:

- I'm pretty sure that functionally these two are identical. (from decompiled code)
- I strongly prefer `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")`. (e.g. gradle errors contain `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm`, not `kotlin("jvm")`)
- Some (most?) docs use `kotlin("jvm")` [kotlinlang.org/..](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#targeting-the-jvm),
  but `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")` is also used [plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm) [docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_libraries.html](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_libraries.html),
  so "undocumented way" should not apply.
- I assume I am missing something, because I fail to understand the reason for existence of `kotlin("jvm")`. (actually I got two theories, both of which seem subpar: 17 characters seemed very important to somebody, "coolness" factor)

Comment: If you navigate to source you’ll find that they’re literally the same thing. I personally find `kotlin(“jvm”)` more readable.